# Angular canDeactivate not working and value showing null

Tags: angular, angular7, candeactivate

I am following link from : https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-candeactivate-guard-example and nothing is working for me in my real world application. I have below code.

AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [DirectAccessGuard, PendingChangesGuard, DialogService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

DialogService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DialogService {

  confirm(message?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const confirmation = window.confirm(message || 'Are you sure?');

    return Observable.of(confirmation);
  }
}
```

AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SidebarPageLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      ..........
      ..........
      {
        path: 'employee/:programId',
        canActivate: [DirectAccessGuard],
        canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard],
        pathMatch: 'full',
        loadChildren: './employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule'
      },
      ......
      .........
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

PendingChangesGuard

```
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ProgramComponent } from '../employee/employee.component';
import { DialogService } from '../services/dialog.service';

export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<EmployeeComponent> {

  constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) { }

  canDeactivate(component: EmployeeComponent, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    const url: string = state.url;
    console.log('Url: ' + url);

    if (!component.isUpdating && component.form.dirty) {
      component.isUpdating = false;
      return this.dialogService.confirm('Discard changes for Country?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

NOTE: I am using Template Driven Forms and `PendingChangesGuard` class's method `canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate...)` where `component` variable is always coming null

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement guard to lazyload module use [canLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) Instead of canActivate.

Then Try moving CanDeactive inside EmployeeModule routes configuration.

**employeeModule.routes.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ {
        path: '',
        componenent: EmployeeComponent,
        canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard],
 }]
```

Comment: Sorry I am not clear with you code.I want to show alter in case if user did some update and without saving data, trying to move to different page

Comment: Can you share employeemodule route config as well?

Comment: If you try to move EmployeeComponent to another page your candeactivate will be triggered. So instead of providing canDeactive to module level provide canDeactive to component level

Comment: As per link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16868 it seem some issue with LazyLoading. Also, EmployeeComponent  moved out to another page ? What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Lazy Loading always showing component details as null when working with lazy loading

Comment: This looks useful: https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/, but still not working for me

Comment: This is bug : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28730

Comment: You want to trigger CanDeactivate when you want to navigate from employee module to some other page right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200409/discussion-between-paa-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 0):

1. In the best practices, so that the guard can be used in any component, the Guard class PendingChangesGuard, should implement the interface not the component. Here, the interface is ComponentCanDeactivate:
   **PendingChangesGuard**
    `export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate>`
2. The component Module SidebarPageLayoutComponent.module.ts should declare the Guard in two places:

   **SidebarPageLayoutComponent.module.ts**
   `const routes: Routes = [
       {
           path: '...',
           component: SidebarPageLayoutComponent,
           canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard] 
       }
   ];
   @NgModule({
       imports: [
          ...,
           RouterModule.forChild(routes)
       ],
       declarations: [SidebarPageLayoutComponent],
       providers: [PendingChangesGuard]
   })
   export class SidebarPageLayoutComponentModule {
   }`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: my case is aslo same but thhe solution given here is not working can any one help me if you want i can post a new Question